# Error setting capabilities, capability management disabled;

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, syslog, syslog-ng

```
root@monitor:/opt/observium# service syslog-ng restart
Stopping system logging: syslog-ng.
Starting system logging: syslog-ngsyslog-ng: Error setting capabilities, capability management disabled; error='Operation not permitted'

root@monitor:/opt/observium# uname -a
Linux monitor 2.6.32-042stab075.2 #1 SMP Tue Mar 5 15:21:53 MSK 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is this an issue with the Kernel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is a known issue with some combinations of `syslog-ng`, `glibc` and kernel versions.

It is not very well documented, but there are references in the [balabit](http://www.balabit.com/) site. This is just one [example](http://communities.balabit.com/balabit/topics/eventfd_error_syslog_ng_and_archlinux).

In Debian, set `SYSLOGNG_OPTS="--no-caps"` in `/etc/default/syslog-ng` to workaround this issue.